# Chained dropdown with bootstrap selectpicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using [Bootstrap-select - Silvio Moreto](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and having two drop-down options.

```
<strong>Option 1</strong>
<select class="selectpicker" name="number">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br />

<strong>Option 2</strong>
<select class="selectpicker" name="abc">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

and jQuery code is:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
     style: 'btn-info',
     size: 4
});
```

Now what I am trying is:

- If user select `3` from First Option, I want to set `C` value selected from Second Option and same reverse method with Second Option is used.
- If user select `C` from Second Option, I want to set `3` value selected from First Option.

I have wrote bellow jQuery code and it is working with only First Option but not with Second Option.

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
    var opValue = $('.selectpicker').val();
    $('.selectpicker').val(opValue);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

NOTE: In my example value will be same and it will be not change.

Here is JSFiddle sample code: [http://jsfiddle.net/user/mananpatel/](http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/RUAS4/124/)

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
     style: 'btn-info',
     size: 4
 });

 $('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
     var opValue = $(this).val();
     console.log(opValue);
     $('.selectpicker').val(opValue);
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
 });
```

Use `$(this)` to get the value of the selected combo. In your code you are always using the value of the first combo.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RUAS4/126/

Comment: Thanks for your great support. Code is working perfect for me. :)

Comment: Your welcome. Best luck with that. Sorry bad english =).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("select").val($(this).val());
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUAS4/128/)